# How to read in .HTM into R as a data frame?

Tags: r, data-science, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I conduct backtesting for some of my trading and I have very large `.HTM` files that are local. They are about 250mb a piece and I am having trouble reading them into R to conduct some data analysis on the dataset. I have tried to copy and paste the data from the local file, into excel, then to read into R, but the file is so large that I am unable to copy all of the data into excel successfully before the webpage or excel crashes.

I am trying to conduct the following:

1.Read in `.htm` file successfully into R

2.Parse through the table below the text at the top of the page and the image in the center of the page

3.Place the data that has the columns and rows into a data frame to conduct data analysis

Does anyone have any savy ideas to read in this data? I have tried `getURL`, `read.lines` using packages `RCurl`,`rlist` and `XML` but have not been successful.

I would appreciate any help/feedback

[image: Image for Reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
require(dplyr)
require(plyer)
require(data.table)
require(jsonlite)
require(httr)
require(rvest)
require(XML)
require(plyr)


COLORDER = c("symbol", "code", "type", "expiry", "strike", "premium", "bid", "ask", "volume", "open.interest", "retrieved")


# AUSTRALIAN OPTIONS --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ASX is the Australian Securities Exchange.

URLASX = 'http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/optionPrices.do?by=underlyingCode&underlyingCode=%s&expiryDate=&optionType=B'

getOptionChainAsx <- function(symbol) {
  url = sprintf(URLASX, symbol)

  html <- read_html(url)

  # Use the second element in the list (the first element gives data on the underlying stock)
  #
  options = (html %>% html_nodes("table.options") %>% html_table(header = TRUE))[[2]] %>%
    plyr::rename(c("Bid" = "bid", "Offer" = "ask", "Openinterest" = "open.interest", "Volume" = "volume", "Expirydate" = "expiry",
                   "P/C" = "type", "Margin Price" = "premium", "Exercise" = "strike", "Code" = "code")) %>%
    transform(
      symbol        = symbol,
      code          = code,
      retrieved     = Sys.time(),
      open.interest = suppressWarnings(as.integer(gsub(",", "", open.interest))),
      premium       = suppressWarnings(as.numeric(premium)),
      bid           = suppressWarnings(as.numeric(bid)),
      ask           = suppressWarnings(as.numeric(ask)),
      volume        = suppressWarnings(as.integer(gsub(",", "", volume))),
      expiry        = as.Date(expiry, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
    ) %>% dplyr::arrange(type, strike, expiry)
  options[, COLORDER]
}

getOptionChainAsx("BHP")
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that your `.HTM` file is local, so to read local files below is the code:

```
 rawHTML <- paste(readLines("path/toYour/file.html"), collapse="\n")
```

After reading the raw HTML you can use the below to read the tables:

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
file<-read_html(theurl)
tables<-html_nodes(file, "table") # Here tables contains a list of tables 
table1 <- html_table(tables[4], fill = TRUE) # Extracting 4th table
```